# Optimization passes that convert conditional branches to jumps

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

In an optimizing compiler, redundant code can be many times detected and eliminated by different algorithms, like Value numbering, Sparse Conditional Constant Propagation, etc. In this case, I'm interested in detecting redundant branches. Suppose the target code is

```
block1:
    cmp r1, r2
    jne block3

block2:
    cmp r1, r2
    je block4

block3:
    ...     
block4:
    ...     
...
```

In this case, if control reached `block2` it means that `r1` and `r2` are equal, so the `je block4` can be replaced by `jmp block4`. Furthermore, if instead in block2 said `jne block4`, then we could remove the `je` completely.

Then my question is, what optimization passes catch this kind of code? I guess value numbering could be extended to tackle this, but never saw it in bibliography, so maybe there's a better way.

**Edit:** corrected the first jump, where it said `je block3` it should have said `jne block3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming there are no other branches into block2 from anywhere else, the compiler's boolean propagation should catch that. Of course, depending on the compiler, there are various other phases can can also do the optimization.

Depending on the bool prop algorithm, what could happen is for block 3 to hold a data flow value of "R1 != R2" that will get propagated to all blocks below it. Block 2 will similarly have a value of "R1 == R2" which will also get propagated to subsequent blocks (in accordance to the data flow), thereby removing the dead branch on its way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the names of optimization passes are completely standardized, and I can't locate my copy of [Muchnick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558603204) at the moment, but in the compiler I worked on last, the situation you describe would be detected in two stages - one optimization pass would detect that the secondary compare is redundant, and remove it, and a subsequent pass would detect that the equal jump does not need to be conditional.

But not every compiler does this type of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization usually happens long before you get to assembly, but rather some form of intermediate representation.

Different forms of IR vary, but one typical aspect is that they operate on an infinite set of registers, rather than on machine registers, and that each register cannot be changed, only initialized once. (If you need mutable variables, you need to `alloca` a pointer on the stack and then `load`/`store` through it. The first, and hardest, phase of optimization is converting from alloca-based to SSA-based so that all other optimizations, like this one, can be done)

This example uses LLVM IR.

```
define void @func2(i32 %r1, i32 %r2) {
block1:
  %0 = icmp ne i32 %r1, %r2
  br i1 %0, label %block3, label %block2

block2:                                           ; preds = %block1
  %1 = icmp eq i32 %r1, %r2
  br i1 %1, label %block4, label %block3

block3:                                           ; preds = %block2, %block1
  unreachable

block4:                                           ; preds = %block2
  unreachable
}
```

It should be fairly intuitive now that the definition of `%1` can be replaced with `%1 = xor i1 %1, true` (which is what a boolean `not` looks like), and then the constant can be propogated across the sole edge that leads into `block2`.